# Xamarin.Forms - Unit Testing a method that uses ServiceLocator from Autofac

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms, nunit, autofac, service-locator

I am trying to unit test a method in my `MyViewModel` which extends from `BaseViewModel`.  The `BaseViewModel` has a method like this

```
protected bool DoSomething()
{
   if (something)
   {
      ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance ...; //ERROR
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

`DoSomething` is called pretty much in every view model.  The app works as expected but I am trying to unit test (NUnit) and every method that calls `DoSomething` is failing in unit tests

The error I get is

```
error CS0119: 'ServiceLocator' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

The `ServiceLocator` is coming from `Autofac.CommonServiceLocator`

Comment: Based on the [docs here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/csl.html), did you set up a container for the test?

Comment: That said, the service locator pattern is usually seen as an anti-pattern and a code smell. It does at times make unit testing in isolation difficult depending on the design of the system in which it is used..

Comment: The currently shown code does not provide enough context about the problem and may be because of how the sample was simplified. Provide a [mcve] ...

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT No, I have no update